x86 Secured boot: kernel module for signed vanilla kernel
I'm booting a signed vanilla kernel (4.9.20, x64) under secured boot.
It works fine.
Then I tried to 'insmod' a kernel module (ko) that is not signed.
It works fine.
Does it make sense ?
According to all links I found, the kernel module should be also signed.

(a) What does cat /sys/kernel/security/lockdown show?  (b) What does modinfo report for the Kernel module in question?
